# Reverting all commits timestamp 1 hour back and getting "Found nothing to rewrite"

Tags: git, bash, git-filter-branch

I'm trying to fix some issues with the times of my commits using `git filter-branch`

```
git filter-branch --commit-filter -f \
'if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME" = "name" ]; then \
old_date = $GIT_COMMITER_DATE;\
export GIT_AUTHOR_DATE=`date -R -d "$old_date -1 hour`;\
export GIT_COMMITER_DATE=`date -R -d "$old_date -1 hour`;\
fi;\
git commit-tree "$@"
```

I've made sure my name field is right, yet git returns

> Found nothing to rewrite

**EDIT: (after the suggestions)**

```
git filter-branch --commit-filter \
'if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME" = "myusername" ]; then \
old_date=$GIT_COMMITTER_DATE;\
export GIT_AUTHOR_DATE=`date -R -d "$old_date -1 hour"`;\
export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE=`date -R -d "$old_date -1 hour"`;\
fi;\
git commit-tree "$@"'
```

So I'm guessing there is some error with my bash syntax or my approach, yet I can't figure out what

Comment: Re edit: your `--commit-filter` is now `-f` and the large bash text is a (bad) argument to `git rev-list`.

Comment: Thank you I'm actually getting some responses back now and it's what @Schwern pointed about the date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**: Here's flaws I found.

- `$GIT_COMMITTER_DATE` has two T's. :)
- `` GIT_AUTHOR_DATE=`date -R -d "$old_date -1 hour`; `` is missing a closing `"`.
- `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE` is in the format `@1240466185 -0700` which `date` does not understand.  See `git-commit-tree` about the "Git internal format".
- There cannot be a space in bash variable assignments, `old_date=$GIT_COMMITTER_DATE`.
- You shouldn't base `GIT_AUTHOR_DATE` off `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE`, they can be different.

---

**UPDATE2**: The code can be made simpler using `--env-filter`. This is where I've left it. The date parsing is not correct. I was hoping Git would understand `@1240466185 -0700 -1 hour` but it doesn't appear to.

```
git filter-branch -f --env-filter '
    if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME" = "Michael G. Schwern" ]; then
        old_committer_date=$GIT_COMMITTER_DATE;
        old_author_date=$GIT_AUTHOR_DATE;
        export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="$old_committer_date -1 hour";
        export GIT_AUTHOR_DATE="$old_author_date -1 hour";
    fi;
'
```

---

Just from looking at your code, here are the places I'd start debugging.

- If `$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME` is never `"name"`.

  - Use `$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL` if you can, it's likely to be more reliable.
- If `$old_date` is not in a format that `date` likes.
- `$GIT_COMMITTER_DATE` or `$GIT_AUTHOR_DATE` are not in a format git likes.

That first one is most likely.

Comment: I fixed the two flaws and it still persists, will have to look further into the formats of the dates

Comment: @ᴘᴀɴᴀʏɪᴏᴛɪs I found more. Now it's down to making the date conversion work.

Comment: Yes the date is the problem now. I'm getting date: invalid date ‘@1413587734 +0100 -1 hour’ now

Comment: I just need to strip the +0100 at the end, the rest can be read by date just  fine

Comment: @ᴘᴀɴᴀʏɪᴏᴛɪs No, that time zone is important information. Please hold.

Comment: It is but `date` (I think) uses my local timezone which is the same as the commit time zone (since I committed these myself), so I think it will be alright, but I'll wait for your input on that

Comment: @ᴘᴀɴᴀʏɪᴏᴛɪs I've gotten as far as I can get with this. I posted what I've got. Just the matter dealing with that date format is left.

Comment: Thank you I've managed to do it! I've split the date by whitespace, saved the timezone and appended it at the end now it works